# Execute function when I apply filter, material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am working with Material_table, what I am looking for is that when my user applies a filter to send a method

[image]

I want to call this method

```
 const subscribeRemoteRequestsArticle = (id) => {
    subscriptionRemoteRequests = API.graphql(
     .....
     .....
 }
```

Table

```
<MaterialTable
                icons={tableIcons}
                columns={[
                  {
                    field: "clacte",
                    title: props.translate("Key"),
                    /* customFilterAndSearch: (term, rowData) => subscribeRemoteRequestsArticle <-- here perform the test  */  
                  },
                  {
                    field: "nomcte",
                    title: props.translate("Customers"),
                  },
                  {
                    field: "nomemp",
                    title: props.translate("Company Key"),
                  },
                  {
                    field: "nomregion",
                    title: props.translate("Name region"),
                  },
                  {
                    field: "nomgirocom",
                    title: props.translate("Commercial Business"),
                    /* lookup: "NomGiroCom", */
                  },
                ]}
                data={customerList}
                title={props.translate("List of customers")} //
                options={{
                  selection: true,
                  filtering: true,
                  search: false,
                  searchable: false,
                  selectionProps: rowData => ({
                    disabled: rowData.name === 'Mehmet',
                    color: 'primary',

                  })
                }}
                onSelectionChange={SelectRows}
                localization={localization(props)}

              />
```

Someone who can tell me how to do it, or where I can find documentation to answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

Pass your custom function to the `prop` `columns`.

```
<MaterialTable
      columns={[
        {
          title: 'Clave', 
          field: 'clave',
          customFilterAndSearch: (term, rowData) => subscribeRemoteRequestsArticle // here
        }
      ]}

      options={{
        filtering: true
      }}
    />
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? Can be a number of different things, state not updating, awaiting response from the call, etc...